# How can I wipe an encrypted device?

Tags: htc, htc-one-m8

My HTC One (M8) is a little soft-bricked being that the drive is encrypted. 
I can't factory reset in CWM recovery because it says

```
formatting /sd-ext
E: Unknown volume for path /sd-ext
Formatting /sdcard/.android_secure
Error mounting /sdcard/.android_secure
skipping format
formatting /storage/sdcard1/.android_secure
Data wipe complete
press any key to continue
```

I can flash ROMs but my Hboot is 3.16 and I have S-ON. Since firewater is discontinued I can't use that to S-OFF and update.

I have a feeling that my options are to get a Lollipop ROM and then unencrypt (KK uses password not pattern) or have to wipe the device some how.

I do have a custom recovery installed, and the device is rooted.

Comment: Ah! Then the first one might be the way to go: Can you try to manually *format* the corresponding partitions (`/data`, `/cache`) from within the custom recovery? That should equal a factory-reset (background: factory-reset tries to *delete* the contents, which it might fail not being able to decrypt the FS; a *format* doesn't access the existing FS but *replaces* it).

Comment: Yuck. What for does it need to *mount* a partition in order to format it? Makes no sense, as it must be unmounted for that action. Well, the other approach might be a bit risky: Can you `adb shell` into the device while in recovery? You could try to run the corresponding `mkfs` commands manually from the command line. For that, you'd need to know at least the FS used (most likely ext4, but it might be something different) – and I'm not sure about other parameters, so this might need some research in advance.

Comment: I wrote to mount `/system`, not `/data`. Remember: `/data` is encrypted (`/system` hopefully not). If `/system` is already mounted (as you write): can you locate `mkfs.*` somewhere in the places mentioned? Then again, you need to know what FS data and cache partitions are using, and whether there are some specific parameters needed. If you cannot figure that, and as you're "locked out" anyway: if there's only `mkfs.ext4` and `mkfs.vfat`, it's safe to assume data and cache are using EXT4, and you could simply run `/system/xbin/mkfs.ext4 <device>`. AT YOUR OWN RISK that is, I'm not 2B blamed :)

Comment: Can you somehow figure out what it was formatted with currently? Sounds strange to me. Speaking of "encrypted" and "Lollipop", I'd indeed be surprised if it still used ext2. You *could* (theroretically, again your own risk) format it ext2. ext4 is basically ext2+journal, and my guess is OS will use `tune2fs` to adjust that (just checked 1 of my devices: same: only `mkfs.ext2` and `tune2fs` but using ext4). I've never played with that, so I'm no reliable source for further details I'm afraid.

Comment: Cool – congrats! If you "cannibalize" on the comments here, maybe we can do a cleanup afterwards? :)

Comment: Wow – that dead easy! Price: USD 500: 0,95 for doing it – but 499,05 for finding out where #D

Comment: I think the problem was it was below everthing and surely it would just run the same command? but w/e it boots, I've just got to find a lollipop ROM that works with HBOOT 3.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to do this I went to the mounts and storage and used the format /data and /system option. Apparently the other options by themselves (/data and /system) do a different thing. I have a feeling this rebuilt my partition table.

As Izzy suggested I had a look at manually formatting it but it seems that that route is a little short-lived. I'd reccomend for anyone reading this to make sure they try the /sdcard format on the recovery.

in CWM is has these options format `/data` format `/cache` and one that says `format /data and /data/media (/sdcard)` the latter works the former doesn't.

Comment: Strange: wasn't that the first thing I've recommended before we started to go through the other options? Quote: "Can you try to manually format the corresponding partitions (`/data`, `/cache`) from within the custom recovery?" And didn't it fail then? What did you differently here?

Comment: Ah! OK, that explains. Mind integrating that into your answer, and we cleanup comments here as well?